# Using aimaraJS for tree structure creation how to get the specific node selected for performing API action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am using aimaraJS for tree structure creation how to get the specific node selected for performing api action. 
https://www.cssscript.com/pure-javascript-treeview-component-aimarajs/

I want to get the value of the selected node so that it can be used in the aimaraJS controller for sending through API request to fetch data from DB.

Please help me in understanding how to get the value selected?

This is the html which is getting created with single node

```
<div id="div_tree">
    <ul id="tree" class="tree">
        <li class="last" style="background-color: white;">
            <img id="toggle_off" class="exp_col" src="images/collapse.png">
            <span class="node">
<img class="icon_tree" src="../libs/Aimara/images/server.png">
<a>Servers</a>
</span>
            <ul id="ul_node_0" style="display: block;">
                <li class="" style="background-color: transparent;"><img id="toggle_off" class="exp_col" src="images/collapse.png"><span class="node"><img class="icon_tree" src="../libs/Aimara/images/WindowsServer.png"><a>Windows</a></span>
                    <ul id="ul_node_1" style="display: block;">
                        <li class="last" style="background-color: white;"><img id="toggle_off" class="exp_col" src="images/collapse.png" style="visibility: hidden;"><span class="node"><img class="icon_tree" src="../libs/Aimara/images/monitor.png"><a>Janani</a></span>
                            <ul id="ul_node_2"></ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="last" style="background-color: white;"><img id="toggle_off" class="exp_col" src="images/collapse.png"><span class="node"><img class="icon_tree" src="../libs/Aimara/images/linux.png"><a>Linux</a></span>
                    <ul id="ul_node_3" style="display: block;">
                        <li class="last" style="background-color: white;"><img id="toggle_off" class="exp_col" src="images/collapse.png" style="visibility: hidden;"><span class="node"><img class="icon_tree" src="../libs/Aimara/images/monitor.png"><a>janani1</a></span>
                            <ul id="ul_node_4"></ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved it using jquery and getting the .text value of the  attribute on click of it. So now I am able to get the text value inside  and have sent it to angularjs controller using scope in javascript.